# Program to add numbers from keyboard

Tags: java, exception, io

I have a program that adds two numbers given user input from the keyboard. Here it is:

```
package com.sigma.java7;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class Addition {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        System.out.println("Enter A :");
        String numA = br.readLine();
        int a = Integer.parseInt(numA);
        System.out.println("Enter B :");
        String numB = br.readLine();
        int b = Integer.parseInt(numB);
        System.out.println("The Result is : "+(a+b));
        br.close();
    }
}
```

However, i would like to know how to handle if the user enters wrong data, it will show the error message "Incorrect input, enter correct values", and then prompt for correct info again. And if and when user enters correctly, program displays proper results and exits.

Do I use exception handling?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a try catch to do this. For example your code could look like this:

```
do {
    try {
       System.out.println("Enter A :");
       String numA = br.readLine();
       int a = Integer.parseInt(numA);
       break;
    } catch (Exception e /*InputMismatchException e*/) {
       System.out.println("Please fill in a number between –2,147,483,648 and 2,147,483,647");
       //System.out.println(e.printStackTrace()); //Use this to print the error
    }
} while (true);
```

This will throw an exception when the input cannot be parsed to an integer.

Comment: Probably want to wrap in a while loop, as the asker wanted it to continue prompting

Comment: Hmm, seems like a good answer, except that I have only learned about FileNotFoundException, SQLException, ArithmeticExeption, ArrayIndexOutofBoundsExeption, FundsNotAvailableException, and NullpointerException. I am supposed to use one of these

Comment: Change the InputMismatchException to a generic Exception

Comment: @AbhishekMallela If this is an assigment use: 'Exception'. My initial answer had Exception but was edited :)

Comment: Hi Floris, what if the number is really big, bigger than 2^32?

Comment: Then you're dealing with a number too big to store in an int. You'd need a new data type to handle those